# SQL: Split a row into multiple rows based on Fiscal Year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that I can produce the following table,

```
Name    School          Department  StartDate   Enddate
John    ABC School  Math            7/1/2004    7/18/2007
John    ABC School  Science         7/1/2010    Nulll
Steve   XYZ School  English         2/1/2004    9/30/2006
Steve   XYZ School  Geology         10/1/2006   Null
```

I am wondering is there any way to split each row into multiple rows based on fiscal year

```
Name    School          Department  Fiscal Year
John    ABC School  Math            2005
John    ABC School  Math            2006
John    ABC School  Math    2007
John    ABC School  Science 2011
John    ABC School  Science 2012
Steve   XYZ School  English 2004
Steve   XYZ School  English 2005
Steve   XYZ School  English 2006
Steve   XYZ School  Geology 2007
Steve   XYZ School  Geology 2008
Steve   XYZ School  Geology 2009
Steve   XYZ School  Geology 2010
Steve   XYZ School  Geology 2011
Steve   XYZ School  Geology 2012
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And you can deal with NULL end dates using COALESCE

```
SELECT f.name, t.name FROM t
INNER JOIN f
ON f.start BETWEEN t.start AND COALESCE(t.end,CURRENT_DATE)
OR f.end BETWEEN t.start AND COALESCE(t.end,CURRENT_DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there exists a table `f` that defines a fiscal year with a start and an end date, you could do this with something like this:

```
SELECT f.name, t.name FROM t
INNER JOIN f
ON f.start BETWEEN t.start AND t.end
OR f.end BETWEEN t.start AND t.end
```